# Sifting from struts to gwt

Tags: gwt, struts

Now i am working in java web application using struts 1.2 framework. Its good to sift in gwt for my career. I didnt having any knowledge in gwt. please give suggestions..

Comment: Sorry, but do you know google?

Answer (score 0):

Start reading the [turoial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/) and if you like it you can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html).